# Add back WYSIWYG buttons

Tags: 4.7, wysiwyg

I'm upgrading a site from 4.6.x to 4.7.x. I am having trouble understanding how to configure the WYSIWYG to provide the same CKEditor editor buttons as in the 4.6.x version.

I know that I can go to Administer -> Customize Data and Screens -> Display Preferences -> Configure CKEditor. However, I don't see how to add back missing editor buttons.

For instance, I would like to add back the "Align Left", "Center", "Align Right", and "Justify" buttons. I see that there is an empty toolbar group where these should go. In the "Plugins" dropdown, I see "Justify" but I don't see any of the other missing buttons. And I don't see how to get Justify out of the dropdown and into the toolbar.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to i think it is enable the justify Plugin that will then give you the align left button. I would also recommend adding in the Font Plugin as well.

Regards

Seamus

Comment: Seamus, could you explain how I enable the justify plugin? I select it in the dropdown, but I don't understand what to do after that. I've tried hitting the enter key, and the page refreshes but nothing changes.

Comment: I think I must have an issue with my particular instance. I just tried the Civi demo, and things do happen when you hit the enter key when selecting a plugin in the dropdown -- the buttons appear in the editor toolbar. Thanks for your help!

Comment: On the off chance that someone else ends up with the same issue, my issue was due to setting the CIVICRM_TEMPLATE_COMPILEDIR to something besides site/default/files, as described here: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20609